# Identifying best method for solving a $1^{st}$ order O.D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I am faced with this d.e:
$$y' = \frac{2xy+3y^2}{2xy +x^2}$$

I know these methods for solving a $1^{st}$ order, o.d.e:

*Integrating factor
*Separation of variables
*Exact d.e
*Using intgrating factor to transform a d.e to exact d.e

I could try each of these methods in a brute force way until i manage to find a solution for my d.e.
But this is not optimal.

So how do I know which method to use?
In this example and/or in general.

Comment: I assume it is $$y'=\frac{2xy+3y^2}{2xy+x^2}$$

Comment: Maybe you are right. The text was low res and couldnt understand if the power is a 2 or 3. I will edit the question.

Comment: It wouldnt work with the 3 as power?

Comment: Make the change of variable $y(x) = \lambda(x) x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y' = \frac{2xy+3y^2}{2xy +x^2}$$ is a homogeneous equation.

The change of variable $$y=ux$$ will transform the equation into a separable one.

$$ u+xu'=\frac {2u+3u^2}{2u+1} $$

which simplifies to $$ \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{(2u+1)du}{u^2+u}$$